# First API Mashup app

Tags: javascript, react.js, google-maps

The app is functioning but I am not sure if I have done it properly. The code is present in my GitHub [repository](https://github.com/sahil290791/api_mashup/tree/gh-pages). The demo can be viewed [here](https://sahil290791.github.io/api_mashup/).

In this application a user can search for anything in a location of choice. I have used Foursquare (used for getting search results) and the Google Maps API (used for getting location coordinates) for doing this.

#### Components Structure:

```
- Container
  - Header
    - QueryBox
    - SearchBox
  - Body
    - SearchList
      - ListItem
    - Maps
```

Please let me know where I can improve the code.

#### app.js

```
require('./map');
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Container from './mashup';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Container />,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

#### mashup.jsx

```
"use strict";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';

const Container = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            location: 'Chennai',
            lat: '80.27',
            lng: '13.084',
            mapData: {},
            query: "Pizza"
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        this.getCoordinates(this.state.location);
        this.updateMap();
        this.foursquare();
    },
    handleUserInput: function(location, query){
        this.setState({
            location: location,
            query: query
        });
        this.getCoordinates(location);
        this.updateMap();
        this.foursquare();
    },
    getCoordinates: function(location){
        var coordinate="";
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+this.state.location+'&key=AIzaSyBoPJb_zmSTasju-ve2CGU3nQzZwCgYNik',
            method: 'get',
            success: function(data){
                coordinate=data;
                this.setState({
                    lat: coordinate["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"], 
                    lng: coordinate["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"],
                });     
            }.bind(this),
            error:  function(data){
            }
        });
    },
    foursquare: function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll='+this.state.lat+','+this.state.lng+'&query='+this.state.query+'&client_secret=HRDKFPHCHB3VXRKAKZEI0UJBDTKTGPJKJ1VKG3VR11MSI2OI&client_id=G32Z1SB20LPG1UJRLBQV1PKXKTAQV0WIJS50A2F3BD4CKVHN&v=20160623',
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                this.setState({
                    mapData: data
                });
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(data){

            }
        });
    },
    updateMap: function(){
        var map;
        var lat = this.state.lat;
        var lng = this.state.lng;
        function initMap(){
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng)},
            zoom: 8
          });
        };
        initMap();
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Header onUserInput={this.handleUserInput} location = {this.state.location} query={this.state.query} />
                <Body location={this.state.location} lat={this.state.lat} lng = {this.state.lng} mapData={this.state.mapData} />
                <div className="footer">
                    Created by: Sahil Prajapati | 
                    <a href="https://github.com/sahil290791/api_mashup"><i className="fa fa-fw fa-github"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://in.linkedin.com/in/sahil290791"><i className="fa fa-fw fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/@sahilprjpt206"><i className="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


const Header = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            location: this.props.location,
            query: this.props.query
        };
    },
    handleLocationChange: function(location){
        this.props.onUserInput(
          location,this.state.query
        );
        this.setState({location: location});
    },
    handleQueryChange: function(query){
        this.props.onUserInput(
          this.state.location, query
        );
        this.setState({query: query});
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <ul className="container">
                <li className="item brand">
                    <a href="/api_mashup/">Find what you are looking for!</a>
                </li>
                <li className="item">
                    <ul>
                        <li className="">
                            <span>Looking for </span>
                            <QueryBox onUserSelection={this.handleQueryChange}/>
                        </li>
                        <li className="searchBar">
                            <span> in </span>
                            <SearchBar onUserInputs={this.handleLocationChange} />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
});

const QueryBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            query: "Pizza"
        };
    },
    handleTextChange: function(e){
        this.props.onUserSelection(
                e.target.value
            );
        this.setState({ query: e.target.value});
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
                <input type="text" ref="query" value={this.state.query} className="queryBox" onChange={this.handleTextChange} placeholder="Search for" />
            );
    }
});

const SearchBar = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            location: "Chennai"
        };
    },
    handleTextChange: function(e){
        this.props.onUserInputs(
          e.target.value
        );
        this.setState({ location: e.target.value});
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <input type="text" name="search[places]" ref="searchInput" value={this.state.location} onChange={this.handleTextChange} placeholder="Enter location"/>
        );
    }
})

const Body = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="body">
                <SearchList mapData={this.props.mapData} />
                <Maps location={this.props.location} lng={this.props.lng} lat={this.props.lat} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});


const SearchList = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var list = this;
        if (this.props.mapData.hasOwnProperty("response") && this.props.mapData["response"]["venues"].length > 0 ){

            var data = this.props.mapData["response"]["venues"].map(function(venue){
                return (
                    <ListItem placeName = {venue["name"]} location={venue["location"]}/>        
                );
            });
            return (
                <div className="searchResult">
                    {data}
                </div>
            );
        }
        else{
            return (
                <div className="searchResult">
                    <div className="searchItem">
                        No near by places found
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
});

const ListItem = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div className="searchItem" >
                <a onClick={this.handleClick}  href="#" data-title={this.props.placeName} data-lng={this.props.location['lng']} data-lat={this.props.location['lat']}>{this.props.placeName}</a>
                <p className="small">{this.props.location["formattedAddress"].join(", ")}: </p>
            </div>
        );
    },
    handleClick: function(e){
        this.setState({
            lat: e.target.getAttribute("data-lat"),
            lng: e.target.getAttribute("data-lng")
        });
        var latLng = {lat: parseFloat(e.target.getAttribute("data-lat")), lng: parseFloat(e.target.getAttribute("data-lng"))};
        function initMap(){
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: latLng,
            zoom: 20
          });
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            title: e.target.getAttribute("data-title")
          });

        };
        initMap();
    }
});

const Maps = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="maps">
                <div id="map">
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


export default Container;
```

#### map.js

```
window.onload = function(){
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
    });
    }
    initMap();
};
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Find what you are looking for!</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Search Places, Food, API, Foodsquare API">
        <meta name="description" content="A simple website to search for whatever you are looking for on Map">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#FFC259">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "react-container"></div>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCoTjemlc0dGtVSiSr5zjvmIhUjgrFIxvc"></script>
        <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```